# mongo: updating a document by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

OK this should be fairly simple so I think I may be doing a thinking mistake.

I have an existing document. I serve it to the client, together with its ObjectId. The client modifies, and wants to update the document. So it comes with the id - looks to me a good choice to identify which document I want to update (?).

But I get an error:
[MongoError: Mod on _id not allowed]

This is the code which updates (via HTTP PUT):

```
     id = req.body._id
     Item.update({'_id': id }, req.body, (err) ->
```

Comment: you can't change the primary key of the document.  what version are you using?

Comment: appears to be 2.2.4. I don't want to change the key, so maybe I just need to delete it from req.body after I got it to be able to update...but that's weird. Anyway.

Comment: right - if you remove it from the body then you should be able to work around this.  it's been since in the latest dev version so eventually it will work a you would expect. :)

Comment: thanks @AsyaKamsky that's what I finally did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to remove the `_id` key from the "update" object you send. `_.omit` can facilitate this.

```
Item.update {_id: req.body._id}, _.omit(req.body, '_id'), (err) ->
```

Aside: I see people code like this often. Taking input from the browser and just shoving it into your database is a terrible idea from a data integrity and security perspective. Just like most businesses don't just leave their accounting ledgers out on the counter with a pen and ask the customers to write in there unsupervised. Consider enforcing your data schema, authorization, and some validations.

Comment: OK, so that's what I did myself too - delete the _id from the req.body. I agree and I am actually a bit worried from a security point of view mostly. But most data is free text Strings, so not sure what kind of validations I could do? But the data is security sensitive, so what would be a correct approach then?

Comment: I do some basic checks before about who can save this data, based on one parameter in the body and the current user's role.

Comment: Integrity, authorization, and security are broad topics so I can't just tell you the "correct" approach, but my hope is you'll take away the idea that this code is ripe for problems. What if the body isn't even an Item-shaped document at all due to a bug? Is your server going to crash when it tries to manipulate that document? Are you OK with an attacker uploading a 16MB payload? Can I just change the accountId on my Item and steal people's stuff?

Comment: Your right of course. I believe these things also happen often when you start learning a new technology. When you check the tutorials and example apps, almost none give weight to these issues. So most people will stick with that example-never-meant-to-go-live code until shit happens...